# Can I use ADtree on supervied data?

Tags: machine-learning, decision-tree

I'm working on supervied data which is contains from 1200 attributes and 450 instances.
I have tried many decistion trees in order to get good accuracy but none of them gave me the best solution as ADtree (Alternating decision tree) gave me.

The problem is that ADtree is using Boosting algorithm and from my undestanding these algorithms are not so good because they can cause duplicate insances in the train and in the test..

My work is needed to be validate (by cross validation) and I'm not sure I am able to use ADtree.

My question is: can I use this tree?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean with "is using Boosting algorithm and from my undestanding these algorithms are not so good because they can cause duplicate insances in the train and in the test".

Answer (score 2):

> The problem is that ADtree is using Boosting algorithm

ADtrees are not boosting algorithms and do not use boosting. You can apply boosting to ADtrees provided the implementation supports weighted data points.

> from my undestanding these algorithms are not so good because they can cause duplicate insances in the train and in the test

Your understanding is completely wrong and not remotely accurate.

> My work is needed to be validate (by cross validation) and I'm not sure I am able to use ADtree.

If you understood cross-validation and what you were doing this would be obviously fine. The question is never "can I use this model in cross validation" but "is cross validation valid for my data?"

> My question is: can I use this tree?

Yes, but you clearly need to learn more about what you are doing before you blindly try and solve problems. [Coursera has a fine online introduction](https://www.coursera.org/course/ml).

Comment: I have searched Coursera and didn't find any information  regarding AD-tree, did you see any?

Comment: This issue is that you don't seem to understand any Machine learning. There is no reason to expect you can really understand any single algorithm without beginning with the foundations of the field. Since AD trees are not popular, you will mostly find the important information in the paper that introduced AD trees. Again, you need the foundational understanding first before you really try and read a paper.